# Get previous page link After refreshing the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a website with WordPress.

I try to get the previous page link with the  `wp_get_referer` function.

The problem is when the user is refreshing the page the value of this function is empty. How can I solve it?

Comment: If the user traversed your site, then use localStorage, if not, not possible

Answer (score 2):

After you've gotten the referring value via `wp_get_referer()`, you'll need to save it for this user in a cookie.

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
function getReferer() {
  // check for a referer
  $referer = wp_get_referer();

  // if there is one, save it to a cookie
  if (!empty($referer)) {
    setcookie("referer_url", $referer, time()+3600);
  }
  // if no referrer, check for a previously-saved cookie
  else {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['referer_url'])){
      // sweet, get it from the cookie
      $referer = $_COOKIE['referer_url'];
    }
  }

  return $referer;
}
```

Now, wherever you need to try to get the referer somewhere in your template or plugin files:

```
$referer = getReferer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` link back to previous page